# Spring DataJPA: what kind of relationship is this, and how can i map it

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities, User and Message. A Message Entity contains 2 fields of type User.

like this:

```
public class Message extends DefaultEntity {


    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="sender")
    private User sender;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="receiver")
    private User receiver;


    @NotNull
    private String message;
}
```

1. is this a one to many or a many-many
2. how can i then map the Message field in the User Entity, because each user should have a list of messages.

thank you

Comment: a messaage can have only one sender right?

Comment: @pvpkiran, yes, one send and one Receiver, but both of them are users

Answer (score 0):

In your user class just use the reverse @OneToMany

But the way you have it set up it looks like a one to one relationship with only one receiver and one sender. So it looks like you should use @OneToOne and maybe specify a join column with @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID").

Assuming that you are using Hibernate.

Comment: i cannot use a one to one, cause hibernate will crash in my senario.....look at it this way. i am creating a mini facebook. there are many messages. and a messages often is between two people/users